# Durandal Initial Issues with running js functions and caching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, durandal

I am playing around with the Durandal Starter Kit for ASP.Net MVC.  Getting on fairly well but I now have two issues:

1. How can I run a function after the shell view has loaded.  I need to find the height of a dom element in the shell.html but won't work in the ViewModel activate method because the View has not yet loaded so I get a null value.  I can't seem to put script in the shell view itself  either.
2. Every time I change the layout, a css value, some text, anything, I have to delete my cache for the application to update, is there some global value somewhere doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1: You can use the viewAttached method.

Here you can see the life cycle:
http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Hooking-Lifecycle-Callbacks/

For 2: If using chrome, the developer tools have an option to disable cache. I think that other browsers will have something similar.

Comment: But is there a way to stop the caching, I'm concerned when I update to release users won't see the up to date version.  I did set cacheViews:false but didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: The cache has nothing to do with durandal, it's your browser who is caching the files. the cacheView option it's for other thing.

Comment: I don't get the same issue with any other project I debug?? I have applied the viewAttached and that works now thanks.

Comment: Looking at Durandal docs it says this for debugging: 
Note: During application development, make sure your browser is set up to ignore it's cache or you may not get your latest JS/HTML changes.
That explains it, thanks.